# on top Qt application in windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

How can I make my application always be on top meaning that the user couldn't access start menu or desktop in Qt or any other possible c++ way?
Also i need it to start right after the login progress , more like a new gui for windows , a simpler one

Comment: There's no API for this and it's usually not possible (and that's a good thing) in the window management of recent Windows versions. There might be ways, but from within the application itself.

Comment: I've seen applications that did something like this like Smart Play or cafe net managers that they only allow you to use their own interface and lunch a few predefined applications through their gui.

Comment: This is possible in Linux. most recent distributions use systemd, through which you can start up custom applications instead of the display manager. If you wish to achieve this in Linux, I can post the steps

Comment: thanks but I'm familiar with that concept...but the application will be used to run games in windows platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)` should do the trick. Note that on some window managers on X11 you also have to pass Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint for this flag to work correctly.